# Custom ascx control in modal pop up panel disappears after it triggers a postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax, postback

I have an ascx control loaded inside a panel tied to a modal pop up panel extender.

The problem is that an action triggered by the ascx control causes a postback; when the postback completes, the panel controlled by the modal popup extender which contains the custom ascx control disappears.

It is merely hidden though with it's default

```
display:none
```

style attributes.

Does anyone know how to remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few guesses - if you are loading the control dynamically in the panel then you should load in every post-back including partial post-back. Another issue can be check if Visible property of Panel or its parent is getting set to false accidentally when post-back occurs.